# Script to copy Exchange Distribution Groups from one user to another

Tags: powershell, script, office365, exchange, microsoft

I am hoping to get some help with a script to copy Exchange group permissions from one user to another. I currently have a script that works to copy mailbox permissions from one user to another but would like to expand it so that it can do Distribution Groups as well.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$FUser = Read-Host "Enter the email address of the user you want to copy mailbox permissions from"
$TUser = Read-Host "Enter the email address of the user you want to set mailbox permissions for"

$GPerm = Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User $FUser

$GPerm | ForEach-Object { $_ 
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Identity -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -User $TUser
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity $_.Identity -AccessRights SendAs -Confirm:$false -Trustee $TUser
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. I know there are guides doing exactly this several places online because I've used them myself.

Comment: @music2myear Can you direct me to those guides as I could not find anything specific to DLs? I've tried changing the above mentioned script to the DLs commands, but would not work.